# C - Error -1073741819 when trying to run makefile for my sudoku solver

Tags: c, makefile, runtime-error

I'm having a problem with my makefile whenever I try to run it. I've been looking all over the web, but I can't find any solutions. It's for a sudoku solver C application that runs on the command prompt.

My makefile is:

```
CFLAGS = -I$(IDIR)

IDIR = ./include/
SRCDIR = ./src/

SOURCES = $(SRCDIR)*.c

all: sudoku run clean

sudoku:
    $(CC) $(SOURCES) $(CFLAGS) -o $@
    
run:
    ./sudoku

clean:
    rm sudoku
```

And the output I get when I try to run it is:

`make: *** [makefile:15: run] Error -1073741819`

Comment: This likely has nothing to do with your makefile.  Have you debugged your program?

Comment: There must be a bug somewhere in the soduku solver. `-1073741819` is a Windows system error number that basically tells you that the program has crashed, presumably because there are bugs. Without seeing some source code we can't help you. It's most likely not related to your makefile, you need to debug this.

Comment: Oh, darn! Okay, would it help if I upload my code? I have it in different c files, so it's not gonna be exactly easy to check.

Comment: If you need help tracing the error, [edit] your question with a [mcve].

Comment: Okay, I'll try to reduce and conquer checking every function in my code, for now I'll upload my main file.